# d3.js - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getBoundingClientRect'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, d3.js, jsfiddle

Please find this : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LrSz/98/)

On jsfiddle chart is working fine. I can plot a point on chart on clicking.
But when I've integrated this code in `backbone` and built with `grunt`, it gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getBoundingClientRect'`.

Please find below the code of `click` event:

```
// Ignore the click event if it was suppressed
              if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) { return; }              
            var myElem = this.$('#point');            
             if (myElem == null) 
              {
              // Extract the click location\    
              var point = d3.mouse(d3.select("g")), p = {x: point[0], y: point[1] };              
              // Append a new point
              this.svg.append("circle")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")")
                  .attr("r", "5")
                  .attr("class", "dot")
                  .attr("id", "point")
                  .style("cursor", "pointer")
                  .call(this.drag);
                }
```

**Why is it running fine on jsfiddle and gives an error on local machine ????**

**How do I resolve this issue ???**

Answer (score 1):

You changed the code from jsfiddle example. Your jsfiddle contains:

```
    var point = d3.mouse(this), 
        p = { x: point[0], y: point[1] };
```

Your code shown here is different:

```
    var point = d3.mouse(d3.select("g")),
        p = { x: point[0], y: point[1] };
```

And that is the line which produce error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'getBoundingClientRect'`

Put there

```
    console.log(this);
    console.log(d3.select("g"));
```

and you will see in console two completely different objects.

Answer (score 0):

[d3.mouse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_mouse) expects a DOM element, not a d3 selection. Try this instead:

```
var point = d3.mouse(d3.select('g').node());
```